# Allow javascript inside iframe (Adding html file from google webdesigner)

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-web-designer

We have many animations generated by Google webdesigner which popups when user click on some td element.
I've found that the only way to add these animations is have a iframe, so we have a fixed iframe where we update src with these animations

Edit.cshtml:

```
<iframe id="popUpFrame"></iframe>
<script src="~/js/popUp/popUp.js"></script>
```

On end of this file we have several "apps" created by Google webdesigner (generated to html file)
Element with id 01 is td element which listen on click

```
// PopUps
let frame_elem = document.getElementById("popUpFrame")
//speedtest popup-01
let speedtest_elem = document.getElementById("01")
hoPopUp(frame_elem, speedtest_elem, "505px", "505px", "/images/PopUps/01.html")
```

popup.js file:

```
function hoPopUp(frame_elem, td_elem, width, height, file_path){
    frame_elem.style.width = width
    frame_elem.style.height = height
    frame_elem.style.top = "50%"
    frame_elem.style.left = "50%"
    td_elem.addEventListener("click", function () { showIframe(frame_elem, file_path) })
    td_elem.addEventListener("mouseout", function () { hideIframe(frame_elem) })

}

function showIframe(frame_elem, file_path) {
    frame_elem.setAttribute("src", file_path)
    frame_elem.classList.add("active")
}

function hideIframe(frame_elem){
    frame_elem.classList.remove('active')
    frame_elem.removeAttribute('src')
}
```

The google webdesigner html file is full of javascript code, but I dont know how to allow it. We've found out that Add blocker is blocking it so we create detection of add blocker by sending some fetch request to some add, but my colleague is using uBlocker where the detection mechanism is not working.

Question is, how to allow running the javascript inside the iframe. Why are the browser tools blocking javascript "downloaded" from my own website?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

uBlocker is doing some "cosmetic filtering", so add detection by sending some javascript fetch Request doesnt work...

Instead of trying detect browser's tool, we put a note to every webdesigner generated html code:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; position:absolute; top:50%;">
          <p style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
              Please disable add blocker and content filters on this site
          </p>
      </div>
```

If the javascript is allowed to run inside the iframe with the webdesigner html code, the animation will be over this note